# Mysql driver error (Jersey Tomcat)

Tags: java, mysql, jersey, jax-rs, tomcat8

I have made a Jersey maven project with Tomcat, now I want to connect it to Mysql database. I go to *Data source explorer -> database connection -> new driver definition*  but when I choose MySQL JDBC Driver , this message comes

**`Unable to locate JAR/zip in file system as specified by the driver definition: mysql-connector-java-4.0.0-bin.jar.`**

I think there should be a dependency on POM.xml or something like that , I have no idea about maven

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Eclipse we need to add Jar file from external source. It has noting to do with the project.

```
In the source explorer -> database connection -> new driver definition page select External jar file and select appropriate jar file for MySql.
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I removed the existing JDBC driver and downloaded the latest version (mysql-connector-java-5.1.37.zip) the instant error message disappeared, but after inserting database name,username and password now I have
Could not connect to New MySQL.
Error creating SQL Model Connection connection to New MySQL. (Error: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver)
com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
Error creating JDBC Connection connection to New MySQL. (Error: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver)
com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Comment: can you check if you are able to connect to the database from mysql-workbench using the same credentials

Comment: yes in workbench I can run queries and work with tables

Comment: can it be my antivirus problem ? ESET smart security ?

Comment: Are the server machine and client machine same. And check it once after turning off the firewall and antivirus.

Comment: yes both are running on my laptop , I disabled antivirus and firewall but still pinging fails

Comment: Can you check and let me know the version of driver you selected.while configuring the driver on the driver template page. It must point to MySql JDBC driver version with value 5.1

Comment: I selected 5.1 and the external jar I downloaded is 5.1.37

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93193/discussion-between-vivek-singh-and-amirhm).